# Splitting a css border with a background icon

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to divide a border with a background image. I don't know if this is even possible this way. Hopefully somebody can help me figure out a good clean way to achieve this.

[image]

I'm trying to get the bottom one and that top one is what I have right now.

```
.tinybanner h1 {
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid $green;
    display: inline-block;
    @include adjust-font-size-to(24px);
    background: url('images/tinybanner.png') center bottom no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: No, you can't do it with a background image on the same element to which the border applies. You could however do it with another element inside the one with the border.

Comment: One possibility would be to give the banner image a white background so that it just covers up part of the border, but this wouldn't work if you need the image's background to be transparent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the pseudo-selector `:after`, you can add an element after every h1:

```
h1 {
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid green;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
h1:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%; /* center the element */
    margin-left: -15px; /* shift left by (width+border)/2 */
    display: block;
    content: ''; 
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: green; /* this can of course be a background image, too */
    border: 10px solid white; /* adds a gap to the left and right */
}
```

The reason why I like this approach is because it degrades nicely. If your browser doesn't support the `:after` pseudo-selector, you are still left with the border underneath the header (because it is set on the `h1`, not the pseudo element) and don't see a dangling background image (because it is set on the `h1:after`).

http://jsfiddle.net/stevemchey/YFXGa/

Answer (score 0):

How about using an `:after` sudo-element with left and right borders:

```
.tinybanner h1 {
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    @include adjust-font-size-to(24px);
    background: url('http://placekitten.com/10/20') center bottom no-repeat;
}

.tinybanner h1:after {
    height:1px;
    content:'';
    display:block;
    border-left: 40px solid #00ff00; 
    border-right:40px solid #00ff00;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bhlaird/XSdbs/